# Display current session name

Tags: php, php-5.3

I use this but only one will display...
please help me I need to display same name in a table..

```
<?php

$id=$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_reservation WHERE id = '$id' ");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  echo '<tr class="record" id="'.$row['status'].'">';
  echo '<td style="border-left: 1px solid #C1DAD7;">'.$row['confirmation'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$row['firstname'].' '.$row['lastname'].'</td>';
  echo '<td><div align="right">'.$row['email'].'</div></td>';
  echo '<td><div align="left">';
  echo '</div></td>';
  echo '<td><div align="right">'.$row['status'].'</div></td>';
  echo '<td><div align="center"><a href="#" id="'.$row['confirmation'].'" class="delbutton" title="Click To Delete">delete</a></div></td>';
  echo '</tr>';
}
?>
```

Comment: first write `session_start();` just after `<?php` and check once what `var_dump($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']);` is showing?

Comment: Also where is db connection code? and please stop using `mysql_*` its deprecated now. use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** mysql_* functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared Statements.

Answer (score 0):

Use session_start() at the top

```
<?php
session_start()
$id=$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_reservation WHERE id = '$id' ");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  echo '<tr class="record" id="'.$row['status'].'">';
  echo '<td style="border-left: 1px solid #C1DAD7;">'.$row['confirmation'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$row['firstname'].' '.$row['lastname'].'</td>';
  echo '<td><div align="right">'.$row['email'].'</div></td>';
  echo '<td><div align="left">';
  echo '</div></td>';
  echo '<td><div align="right">'.$row['status'].'</div></td>';
  echo '<td><div align="center"><a href="#" id="'.$row['confirmation'].'" class="delbutton" title="Click To Delete">delete</a></div></td>';
  echo '</tr>';
}
?>
```